# 500 (error in sender) in the WSO2 API Manager quickstart example

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm currently evaluating the WSO2 Software suite and decided to start with the [quickstart example](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/GettingStarted/quick-start-guide/) to take off with prototyping as fast and with as little effort as possible. So I set up a fresh VM, installed all the components and fired up the API manager.

As I mentioned above, I started with the quickstart example from their website which is the simplest thing one can imagine. I followed it step by step to the letter and I got a message informing me about an internal system error. This has something to do with the SSL engine, but I can't really figure out what's wrong.

The response from the API Manager itself:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
  <am:code>101500</am:code>
  <am:type>Status report</am:type>
  <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
  <am:description>Error in Sender</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

And the log from the wso2am server:

```
[2020-02-16 14:10:02,649] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
<trimmed>
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:255) ~[httpcore-nio_4.3.3.wso2v4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:293) ~[httpcore-nio_4.3.3.wso2v4.jar:?]
    ... 9 more
<trimmed>
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:293) ~[httpcore-nio_4.3.3.wso2v4.jar:?]
    ... 9 more
<trimmed>
[2020-02-16 14:10:02,698]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101500, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender
```

(I tried to trim it as best I can as you can see but with no real expertise in Java it's difficult to tell which parts of the trace are relevant)

Comment: Did you use https as the backend endpoint protocol?

Comment: Yes! This was exactly the issue! However I'm wondering how did that happen -- I have spent a fair amount of time looking for the cause of the problem, I've actually executed the entire tutorial from scratch twice... So I'm wondering how did that "s" end up in the URL. I've literally copied the URL from the tutorial in the most braindead fashion possible. Is it possible it got changed to https:// by default on the way?

Comment: @Menaka Maybe you'd like to submit this as an answer?

Comment: @KrzysiekSetlak Yes, we fixed that recently.